# how to merge two git commits into one?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

i have made two commits while in fact one commit is enough, the reason that i make two commits is because i forget to add one file after i make the first commit, so i add it and make another commit, after that i found that i find i have made two commit with the same comment, so how to merge these two commits into one?

```
* 3e381e7 - (HEAD, master) now i have add load script which can open many pages automatically at one time (4 seconds ago) 
* 2d97025 - now i have add load script which can open many pages automatically at one time (21 seconds ago)
```

how to merge commits 3e381e7 and 2d97025 so that there is only one commit log?

Comment: For future reference, use the `--amend` flag to edit the previous commit instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Interactive [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)  is your friend :

```
git rebase -i
```

You can also do a `git reset --soft` followed by a git `commit --amend` but rebasing is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

Joining two commits into one is called "squashing". Do an interactive rebase,

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

and then in the text editor that opens, change the line with the `2d97025` to start with the word 'squash', then safe the file and exit the editor.

Comment: The line to change to start with squash would be the one containing `3e381e7`, which should be the final line that lists a commit.  And here I'd use `fixup` rather than `squash` since it sounds like the commit message on the first commit was fine.